# Is it permitted to load a full cargo container onto an aircraft without a roller track loading/locking system?

Tags: weight-and-balance, cargo

Aircraft with roller track cargo loading systems transport containers/pallets in the cargo compartments. When an aircraft doesn't consist of a certain system but just a flat floor (so for example a small bulk cargo aircraft), is it allowed (regulation wise), and if the dimensions are no problem, to place one or more (loaded) containers in the aircraft?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I don't really understand your question: why would it not be allowed to put containers into an aircraft? Are you asking if a roller track system is required for all cargo aircraft? Or are you asking how a cargo aircraft is loaded if there are no rollers or other special features?

Comment: The roller systems consist of locks which secure the the containers. When you put a container in an aircraft without roller systems (and without these locks) the container will not be secured. So is it then allowed for the airline to just put a container in such aircraft and secure the containers in their own way?

Comment: It's important to mention what region you're asking about, when you ask about regulations. They can be very different between Europe, USA, China, etc.

Comment: Let's say Europe

Answer (score 1):

(I just saw you asked about Europe right as I posted this, if this is not applicable any more I will remove it)

If Im reading this correctly the question is asking "how is cargo secured if not loaded through the use of a [Unit Load Device (ULD)](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/unit-load-devices/Pages/index.aspx)"

Here in the US under the FAA there are some guide lines for tying down cargo if no ULD is present. You can read them [here (SAFO 13008)](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2013/SAFO13008.pdf) and [here (SAFO 13005)](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2013/SAFO13005.pdf). Much of the over arching information can be found in this [Advisory Circular On Air Cargo Operations (AC 120-85)](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/120-85.pdf).

In short,

> ...The manual must state the policy and provide procedures to determine
>   the intended reaction load for each tie down to ensure sufficient
>   special load restraint for flight loads...

You can tie it down as long as you conform to the above linked documents and ensure the straps and tie downs are sufficient to hold the cargo.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. But if you want to place a loaded ULD in an aircraft, without the proper locks for securing (so also without roller system), is this also allowable? 
(without the question "how are you going to put the loaded container at its place?")

Comment: I actually read the question more along the lines of "may ULDs be loaded into aircraft that are not properly equipped for ULDs". But the question is unclear.

Comment: Under the FAA they dont seem to specify what the cargo is so you could tie down a ULD if need be as I read the regulations.